# Formula adjustment to get circumference of a sentence.

Tags: geometry, education

I want to calculate, automatically, the circumference of random words (written in Arial font) using the height and length.
I used this formula : `(H+L)*4`.

> Nota : I can get the exact circumference in a software (Adobe Illustrator), but I want to calculate it automatically inside a php code.

Then, I run some tests by changing the height or the length of this sentence.
If I keep the the height and change only the length the results are good enough.
But if I change the height and keep the length, the difference between the calculated circumference and the real one is getting bigger proportionally (please take a look to my image).

I'm wondering if we can adjust this formula to get a good result everytime.

Thank you very much.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4mFx.jpg)

Comment: The circumference of a rectangle of height $H$ and length $L$ is $2(H + L)$, not $4(H+L)$.